# Why answer acceptance is not updated, when the same question is open in two browser tabs?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes, live-refresh

When I mistakenly open the same question in two separate browser tabs and upvote and accept an answer in first tab, then -- when I switch to another tab -- I can clearly see, that points are updated, but the fact, that I accepted the answer is not updated.

Why? Cache ("the answer is always... cache")?

Comment: What exactly isn't updated?

Comment: Erh... "Points"? This tiny number between up and down arrows? What did I say in my question?

Comment: Points is usually rep. Do you mean "score"? And as for checkmark, does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, score. Yes, it matters. At least to me. I don't understand the idea of asking, if something is not important. Thus, we may assume, that this really matters to me, since I actually asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not caching or whatever. Do note that if anyone else than you click the checkmark, you'll see it (dis)appear realtime. The point of realtime updates is not to sync your tabs, and as long as the realtime updates work as designed, i.e. syncing client with server so as different clients can see the things realtime, this doesn't matter.

Comment: To be honest, I understand about 10% of your answer. But the most important part -- that this a feature, not a bug -- seems clear to me.